# WMClose() is not working with TForm.CustomTitleBar property and new TTitleBarPanel control

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using the `TForm.CustomTitleBar` property and new `TTitleBarPanel` control, which allow you to customize a VCL form's native title bar similar to Windows Explorer, Google Chrome, or other applications.

The `WMClose()` handler is not working anymore, whereas the old title bar with the default close button works fine, but now it's not automatically hitting the `WMClose()`. Here I am using the new **customeTitle bar** provided by Delphi with `SystemButton` set as `False`.

**.PAS**

```pascal
unit CodeTreeForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  System.Actions,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.TitleBarCtrls,
  Vcl.Menus,
  Vcl.StdActns,
  Vcl.ExtActns,
  Vcl.ActnList,
  Vcl.PlatformDefaultStyleActnCtrls,
  Vcl.ActnMan,
  Vcl.ToolWin,
  Vcl.ActnCtrls,
  Vcl.ActnMenus,
  Vcl.Imaging.pngimage,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TfrmCodeTree = class(TForm)
    TitleBarPanel1: TTitleBarPanel;
    ActionManager1: TActionManager;
    DialogOpenPicture1: TOpenPicture;
    DialogSavePicture1: TSavePicture;
    DialogColorSelect1: TColorSelect;
    DialogFontEdit1: TFontEdit;
    DialogPrintDlg1: TPrintDlg;
    EditCut1: TEditCut;
    EditCopy1: TEditCopy;
    EditPaste1: TEditPaste;
    EditSelectAll1: TEditSelectAll;
    EditUndo1: TEditUndo;
    EditDelete1: TEditDelete;
    FileOpen1: TFileOpen;
    FileOpenWith1: TFileOpenWith;
    FileSaveAs1: TFileSaveAs;
    FilePrintSetup1: TFilePrintSetup;
    FilePageSetup1: TFilePageSetup;
    FileRun1: TFileRun;
    FileExit1: TFileExit;
    BrowseForFolder1: TBrowseForFolder;
    InternetBrowseURL1: TBrowseURL;
    InternetDownLoadURL1: TDownLoadURL;
    InternetSendMail1: TSendMail;
    SearchFind1: TSearchFind;
    SearchFindNext1: TSearchFindNext;
    SearchReplace1: TSearchReplace;
    SearchFindFirst1: TSearchFindFirst;
    ActionMainMenuBar1: TActionMainMenuBar;
    Action1: TAction;
    Action2: TAction;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure pgcRepositoriesMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ActionMainMenuBar1Paint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WMClose(var Message: TWMClose); message WM_CLOSE;
  private
  public
  end;

var
  frmCodeTree: TfrmCodeTree;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TfrmCodeTree.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // The ActionMainMenuBar does not draw correctly in the title bar area. So DoubleBuffered must be enabled, and
  // Transparent must be set to False
  ActionMainMenuBar1.DoubleBuffered := True;
  ActionMainMenuBar1.Transparent := False;
end;


procedure TfrmCodeTree.ActionMainMenuBar1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Paint the background of the ActionMainMenuBar. Please note that for this app, the title bar is always the
  // same color regardless of whether or not the app is active or inactive.
  ActionMainMenuBar1.Canvas.Brush.Color := CustomTitleBar.BackgroundColor;
  ActionMainMenuBar1.Canvas.FillRect( ActionMainMenuBar1.ClientRect );
end;


procedure TfrmCodeTree.pgcRepositoriesMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const
  sc_DragMove = $F012;
begin
  // This event handler allows the user to drag the form around when clicking on the background area of the tab control
  ReleaseCapture;
  Perform( wm_SysCommand, sc_DragMove, 0 );
end;

procedure TfrmCodeTree.WMClose(var Message: TWMClose);
begin
 ;
end;
end.
```

**.DFM**

```
object frmCodeTree: TfrmCodeTree
  Left = 353
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'CodeTree'
  ClientHeight = 598
  ClientWidth = 1101
  Color = clBtnFace
  CustomTitleBar.Control = TitleBarPanel1
  CustomTitleBar.Enabled = True
  CustomTitleBar.Height = 58
  CustomTitleBar.SystemHeight = False
  CustomTitleBar.SystemColors = False
  CustomTitleBar.SystemButtons = False
  CustomTitleBar.BackgroundColor = 7875840
  CustomTitleBar.ForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = 7875840
  CustomTitleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = 7875840
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = 7875840
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonPressedForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = 7875840
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = 7875840
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  FormStyle = fsMDIForm
  GlassFrame.Enabled = True
  GlassFrame.Top = 58
  OldCreateOrder = True
  Position = poDesigned
  ShowHint = True
  StyleElements = [seFont, seClient]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 15
  object TitleBarPanel1: TTitleBarPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 1101
    Height = 57
    CustomButtons = <>
    object Image1: TImage
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 3
      Top = 3
      Width = 24
      Height = 26
      Margins.Right = 10
      Align = alLeft
      AutoSize = True
      Picture.Data = {
        0954506E67496D61676589504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000180000
        001808020000006F15AAAF0000002B744558744372656174696F6E2054696D65
        005475652039204E6F7620323032312030343A33363A3230202D30363030BE05
        0EFB0000000774494D4507E50B090A320919BE3709000000097048597300000B
        1200000B1201D2DD7EFC0000000467414D410000B18F0BFC6105000002064944
        415478DA6364775FC6400DC088DF20415E3609414E20E3C5FBEFEF3FFF22D920
        0E36E6FA38DD440F65011E36B8E0872FBFD61F795C39E70290419441C66A42F3
        4A2DD565F9B0DAFCF4CDB7CC09A7769D794EC0207753C969F966D2225C787CF1
        F8D5B7EC49E866A11824C2CF0E34C5CF4A8660D06E38FA386BE2E9779F7E6237
        C8CB5C6A5DA33D9A47F69C7B0164B81A4B4A0973224BE54E3E3D7BEB1DEC064D
        CA3149F35185730F5D7A15DB7EF4E5FB1F40B6A410E7926A6B6B6D51B8ECB44D
        B78AA69DC56ED0EE6E675B5D3108FBFF7F06FFDA03C801E16126B5A109E1DEFD
        175E7A56ECC36ED0DD25FEF060061AA410B51EE21C08007AEDD6227F38F7DFFF
        FF7C3E2B89725140DDC19DA79FC1651D0CC4A7E79BC1B927AEBF49EC3A4E5418
        1DB9F21A18462FDE7E07B285F9D9ABA274B4E4F9E1B29B8E3D0106137683C2EC
        E517555A21470DD06BD71F7DBCF5F8132303033B1B335C1CE8DE55071FEE0547
        28168384F9D8A71598F9634B47DF7EFE59B6F7C133B0EB80E0E6A34FDB4E3EFD
        FEEB2F768380C0CD0494B26544B1A4EC072FBEB62CBD0C32F4C79FE3D7DE3C87
        198ADD200670B29C5D6C01741DA6592EA57BFFFEFB7FFFF99717EFBEA34961CF
        FD405326E79A06D9CAA289CB45AE07668B3F7FFF636AC1591E3132327CDF1E89
        2C020C604ECFE50C38C04834080852BD55C4051145C7CBF7DF91CB0D120C2209
        50CD2000A463F8F9066871280000000049454E44AE426082}
      Transparent = True
      ExplicitLeft = 0
      ExplicitTop = 0
      ExplicitHeight = 24
    end
    object ActionMainMenuBar1: TActionMainMenuBar
      Left = 0
      Top = 32
      Width = 1101
      Height = 25
      UseSystemFont = False
      ActionManager = ActionManager1
      Align = alBottom
      AllowHiding = True
      Caption = 'ActionMainMenuBar1'
      Color = clMenuBar
      ColorMap.DisabledFontColor = 7171437
      ColorMap.HighlightColor = clWhite
      ColorMap.BtnSelectedFont = clBlack
      ColorMap.UnusedColor = clWhite
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
      Font.Style = []
      Spacing = 0
      OnPaint = ActionMainMenuBar1Paint
    end
  end
  object ActionManager1: TActionManager
    ActionBars = <
      item
        Items = <
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = FileOpen1
                ImageIndex = 7
                ShortCut = 16463
              end
              item
                Action = FileOpenWith1
                Caption = 'O&pen with...'
              end
              item
                Action = FileSaveAs1
                ImageIndex = 30
              end
              item
                Action = FilePrintSetup1
              end
              item
                Action = FilePageSetup1
                Caption = 'Pa&ge Setup...'
              end
              item
                Action = FileRun1
              end
              item
                Action = FileExit1
                ImageIndex = 43
              end
              item
                Action = BrowseForFolder1
                Caption = '&BrowseForFolder1'
              end>
            Caption = '&File'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = EditCut1
                ImageIndex = 0
                ShortCut = 16472
              end
              item
                Action = EditCopy1
                ImageIndex = 1
                ShortCut = 16451
              end
              item
                Action = EditPaste1
                ImageIndex = 2
                ShortCut = 16470
              end
              item
                Action = EditSelectAll1
                ShortCut = 16449
              end
              item
                Action = EditUndo1
                ImageIndex = 3
                ShortCut = 16474
              end
              item
                Action = EditDelete1
                ImageIndex = 5
                ShortCut = 46
              end>
            Caption = '&Edit'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = DialogOpenPicture1
                ShortCut = 16463
              end
              item
                Action = DialogSavePicture1
                ShortCut = 16467
              end
              item
                Action = DialogColorSelect1
              end
              item
                Action = DialogFontEdit1
              end
              item
                Action = DialogPrintDlg1
                ImageIndex = 14
                ShortCut = 16464
              end>
            Caption = '&View'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = SearchFind1
                ImageIndex = 34
                ShortCut = 16454
              end
              item
                Action = SearchFindNext1
                ImageIndex = 33
                ShortCut = 114
              end
              item
                Action = SearchReplace1
                ImageIndex = 32
              end
              item
                Action = SearchFindFirst1
              end>
            Caption = '&Repository'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = InternetBrowseURL1
              end
              item
                Action = InternetDownLoadURL1
              end
              item
                Action = InternetSendMail1
              end>
            Caption = '&Actions'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = Action1
                Caption = '&Options'
              end>
            Caption = '&Tools'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = Action2
                Caption = '&About CodeTree'
              end>
            Caption = '&Help'
          end>
        ActionBar = ActionMainMenuBar1
      end>
    Left = 600
    Top = 270
    StyleName = 'Platform Default'
    object DialogOpenPicture1: TOpenPicture
      Category = 'View'
      Caption = '&Open Picture...'
      Hint = 'Open Picture'
      ShortCut = 16463
    end
    object DialogSavePicture1: TSavePicture
      Category = 'View'
      Caption = '&Save Picture...'
      Hint = 'Save Picture'
      ShortCut = 16467
    end
    object DialogColorSelect1: TColorSelect
      Category = 'View'
      Caption = 'Select &Color...'
      Hint = 'Color Select'
    end
    object DialogFontEdit1: TFontEdit
      Category = 'View'
      Caption = 'Select &Font...'
      Dialog.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Dialog.Font.Color = clWindowText
      Dialog.Font.Height = -11
      Dialog.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Dialog.Font.Style = []
      Hint = 'Font Select'
    end
    object DialogPrintDlg1: TPrintDlg
      Category = 'View'
      Caption = '&Print...'
      ImageIndex = 14
      ShortCut = 16464
    end
    object EditCut1: TEditCut
      Category = 'Edit'
      Caption = 'Cu&t'
      Hint = 'Cut|Cuts the selection and puts it on the Clipboard'
      ImageIndex = 0
      ShortCut = 16472
    end
    object EditCopy1: TEditCopy
      Category = 'Edit'
      Caption = '&Copy'
      Hint = 'Copy|Copies the selection and puts it on the Clipboard'
      ImageIndex = 1
      ShortCut = 16451
    end
    object EditPaste1: TEditPaste
      Category = 'Edit'
      Caption = '&Paste'
      Hint = 'Paste|Inserts Clipboard contents'
      ImageIndex = 2
      ShortCut = 16470
    end
    object EditSelectAll1: TEditSelectAll
      Category = 'Edit'
      Caption = 'Select &All'
      Hint = 'Select All|Selects the entire document'
      ShortCut = 16449
    end
    object EditUndo1: TEditUndo
      Category = 'Edit'
      Caption = '&Undo'
      Hint = 'Undo|Reverts the last action'
      ImageIndex = 3
      ShortCut = 16474
    end
    object EditDelete1: TEditDelete
      Category = 'Edit'
      Caption = '&Delete'
      Hint = 'Delete|Erases the selection'
      ImageIndex = 5
      ShortCut = 46
    end
    object FileOpen1: TFileOpen
      Category = 'File'
      Caption = '&Open...'
      Hint = 'Open|Opens an existing file'
      ImageIndex = 7
      ShortCut = 16463
    end
    object FileOpenWith1: TFileOpenWith
      Category = 'File'
      Caption = 'Open with...'
      FileName = ''
    end
    object FileSaveAs1: TFileSaveAs
      Category = 'File'
      Caption = 'Save &As...'
      Hint = 'Save As|Saves the active file with a new name'
      ImageIndex = 30
    end
    object FilePrintSetup1: TFilePrintSetup
      Category = 'File'
      Caption = 'Print Set&up...'
      Hint = 'Print Setup'
    end
    object FilePageSetup1: TFilePageSetup
      Category = 'File'
      Caption = 'Page Set&up...'
      Dialog.MinMarginLeft = 0
      Dialog.MinMarginTop = 0
      Dialog.MinMarginRight = 0
      Dialog.MinMarginBottom = 0
      Dialog.MarginLeft = 1000
      Dialog.MarginTop = 1000
      Dialog.MarginRight = 1000
      Dialog.MarginBottom = 1000
      Dialog.PageWidth = 8500
      Dialog.PageHeight = 11000
    end
    object FileRun1: TFileRun
      Category = 'File'
      Browse = False
      BrowseDlg.Title = 'Run'
      Caption = '&Run...'
      Hint = 'Run|Runs an application'
      Operation = 'open'
      ShowCmd = scShowNormal
    end
    object FileExit1: TFileExit
      Category = 'File'
      Caption = 'E&xit'
      Hint = 'Exit|Quits the application'
      ImageIndex = 43
    end
    object BrowseForFolder1: TBrowseForFolder
      Category = 'File'
      Caption = 'BrowseForFolder1'
      DialogCaption = 'BrowseForFolder1'
      BrowseOptions = []
      BrowseOptionsEx = []
    end
    object InternetBrowseURL1: TBrowseURL
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = '&Browse URL'
      Hint = 'Browse URL'
    end
    object InternetDownLoadURL1: TDownLoadURL
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = '&Download URL'
      Hint = 'Download from URL'
    end
    object InternetSendMail1: TSendMail
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = '&Send Mail...'
      Hint = 'Send email'
    end
    object SearchFind1: TSearchFind
      Category = 'Repository'
      Caption = '&Find...'
      Hint = 'Find|Finds the specified text'
      ImageIndex = 34
      ShortCut = 16454
    end
    object SearchFindNext1: TSearchFindNext
      Category = 'Repository'
      Caption = 'Find &Next'
      Hint = 'Find Next|Repeats the last find'
      ImageIndex = 33
      ShortCut = 114
    end
    object SearchReplace1: TSearchReplace
      Category = 'Repository'
      Caption = '&Replace'
      Hint = 'Replace|Replaces specific text with different text'
      ImageIndex = 32
    end
    object SearchFindFirst1: TSearchFindFirst
      Category = 'Repository'
      Caption = 'F&ind First'
      Hint = 'Find First|Finds the first occurance of specified text'
    end
    object Action1: TAction
      Category = 'Tools'
      Caption = 'Options'
    end
    object Action2: TAction
      Category = 'Help'
      Caption = 'About CodeTree'
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have any problems with the `WM_Close` message. Perhaps you should show the content of your `.dfm` file.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Please check the .pas and .dfm above. I am using the SystemButton setting as False

Comment: Why are you catching the `WM_CLOSE` message directly at all?  The Form already does that internally for you.  To react to the Form closing, use its `OnClose(Query)` event(s) instead.

Comment: as there is some custom function written over WM_Close in our original code which we are posting from many places in our app so calling OnClose we need to again post WM_Close explicitly